# Accessing Tables outside of Babelfish_DB

Tags: postgresql, babelfish

Can I access data from tables that are not part of the Babelfish_DB?

I have tried

```
USE AnotherDatabase
SELECT * FROM sys.tables -- Returns all DB's defined in the Babelfish_DB scope?
SELECT * FROM TableInBabelFishDBScope -- works fine
SELECT * FROM MyExistingTableInAnotherDatabase --errors out, can't be found.
```

It appears that BabelFish_DB represents a SQL Server instance because I can see all the meta data tables in there. Can I create and/or access tables in other postgresql databases, at the moment I get an error when I try (could be human error/lack of understanding). If I am supposed to use the Babelfish_DB as the container for all babel-fish enabled DB's and commands could someone post documentation on this aspect?

Comment: You refer to Microsoft SQL Server in the question but have tagged it PostgreSQL. Which are we dealing with?

Comment: @RichardHuxton babelfish translates sql server TDS to postgres supported commands. It is an optional feature to a postgress cluster in aws. I was hoping to reach a wider audence by taging postgres as it is the targeted rdms.

Comment: Ah, OK. PostgreSQL doesn't support cross-database queries without using foreign tables or dblink or some such. So maybe your "USE" doesn't actually reconnect to the requested db.

Comment: @RichardHuxton - Thanks for the reply. Babelfish abstracts multiple databases (in T-SQL parlance) via schema naming, and they all reside in the babel fish database. I will add notes to the answer as it may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence, only artifacts created via Babelfish are assessable to Babelfish and Databases outside of the Babelfish_DB cannot be accessed via Babelfish.

All (T-SQL) created databases reside inside the BableFish_DB. Artifacts added outside of BF are not registered with Babelfish. For example, if a database name Database1 was created via Babelfish containing a table named Table1 and later a Table named Table2 was created with, for example, PgAdmin. The following (TSQL) command over Babelfish would fail `SELECT * FROM Table2` *relation "table2" does not exist*

In multiple-instance mode, multiple databases are abstracted away inside the BF databases via schema naming semantics -> `<DatabaseName>_<SchemaName>`.

In single-instance mode, there is only support for one database thus the schema is simply -> `<SchemaName>`.

If anyone finds inaccuracies in any of the above, please feel free to correct me.

```
USE TestDB1
SELECT * FROM Table1 --No schema created - Using Shema TestDb1_dbo

USE TestDB2
SELECT * FROM TestSchema.Table1 -- Schema TestSchema created against TestDB2 - using TestDB2_TestSchema

USE TestDB3
SELECT * FROM TestSchema.Table1 -- Schema TestSchema created against TestDB3 - using TestDB3_TestSchema
```